# Asp.net Asynchronous http web request

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

i am facing problem in reading the full content from the response, the length of the decoder is not coming as per the length of the response content, i am having problem in line

```
int read = responseStream.EndRead(asyncResult);
```

//the value of read is very less in accordance to the response.

```
int len = rs.StreamDecode.GetChars(rs.BufferRead, 0, read, charBuffer, 0);
```

below is my code for the same

```
private void ReadQtoRCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
   // Get the RequestState object from AsyncResult.
   RequestState rs = (RequestState)asyncResult.AsyncState;

   // Retrieve the ResponseStream that was set in RespCallback. 
   Stream responseStream = rs.ResponseStream;

   // Read rs.BufferRead to verify that it contains data. 
   int read = responseStream.EndRead(asyncResult);
   if (read > 0)
   {
      // Prepare a Char array buffer for converting to Unicode.
      Char[] charBuffer = new Char[BUFFER_SIZE];

      // Convert byte stream to Char array and then to String.
      // len contains the number of characters converted to Unicode.
      int len = rs.StreamDecode.GetChars(rs.BufferRead, 0, read, charBuffer, 0);

      String str = new String(charBuffer, 0, len);

      // Append the recently read data to the RequestData stringbuilder
      // object contained in RequestState.
      RequestData.Append(PureAnalyzer_WebApp.DoubleAt + rs.ResultName + PureAnalyzer_WebApp.DoubleColon);

      // ESResultBE ESObj = new ESResultBE();
      System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer JsonSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
      ESResultBE ObjESResultBE;
      string Result = "";         

      RequestData.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rs.BufferRead, 0, read).ToString());

      // Continue reading data until 
      // responseStream.EndRead returns –1.
      IAsyncResult ar = responseStream.BeginRead(
                           rs.BufferRead, 0, BUFFER_SIZE,
                           new AsyncCallback(ReadQtoRCallBack), rs);
   }
   else
   {
      // Close down the response stream.
      responseStream.Close();
      if (ResponseFlag[rs.ResultName] != "1")
      {
        ResponseFlag[rs.ResultName] = "1";
        CompleteCount++;
      }
      // Set the ManualResetEvent so the main thread can exit.
      allDone.Set();
   }
   return;
}
```

Comment: have you looked at async, await with .net 4.5 ? async calls have become very easy. unless you have to use this one, you might consider using async, await and HttpClient async calls. much more simpler.

Comment: actually it is urgent, but i will consider and look for this later, but for now i need some kind of solution with the existing code that i have used.